# Why "list.append(str(d) for d in devices) "returns only a generator and does not populate the list?

Tags: python-3.x, list

I have a list of objects and i want to create another list of strings.
If I run the append function this way:

`list_new.append(str(d) for d in devices)`

the `list_new` elements will be:

`[<generator object <genexpr> at 0x0000018F0E9DFF48>]`

Why is this behaviour?

Comment: what is `devices` here ?

Comment: @Gary it does not matter

Answer (score 3):

```
list_new.append(str(d) for d in devices)
```

In this case, `str(d) for d in devices` evaluates first to a generator, then this generator is appended to the list. Nothing here calls `append` over each element in `devices`.

This could be solved in several different ways, some are idiomatic and some are frowned upon.

The best in this case, use `extend`:

```
list_new.extend(str(d) for d in devices)
```

This will take each element in the generator and add it to the list independently.

The next best thing is a proper loop:

```
for d in devices:
    list_new.append(str(d))
```

You could use a list comprehension if `list_new` starts empty:

```
list_new = [str(d) for d in devices]
```